# Sketch the region of interest of a double integration

Tags: matlab, math

The question is as below:

[image: Equation]

Evaluate the integral and sketch the region of interest.

I tried to code:

```
syms x y 
I=int(int(fun,y^2,1),0,1);
ezplot(I)
```

but it gives me a straight line only.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be like this

```
syms x y 
fun = y*exp(x^2);
I=int(int(fun,x,y^2,1),y,0,1);
ezplot(I)
```

but there is no surprise if you obtain a horizontal line. The result of a definite integral is a number: it is constant. 
An horizontal line is the graph of a function like y = N.

To "see" the integral as a region in the xy plane, it has to be represented as the area under the indefinite integral

```
I2=int(fun,x,y^2,1);
ezplot(I2,0,1)
```

PS I'm not so sure the definite integral from a number to a varialbe is always possible in Matlab